# flexviewer3.0 & wmts basemap

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer, wmts

I'm using fleviewer 3.0 with wmts.
I've got no result.. [white screen]
from server-side i'm using both mapproxy.1.5a & geoserver2.2

my config.xml for flexviewer:

```
 <layer label="Gwc-wmts" type="wmts" visible="true" imageformat="png" 
    url="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts"  
                servicemode="KVP" layerid="cite:my_layer"
                tileMatrixSetId="EPSG:4326"

                /> 

        <layer label="WMtS"
                type="wmts"
                url="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mapproxy/service"
                layerid="my_layer"
                servicemode="KVP"
                imageformat="png"
                visible="true"
                tileMatrixSetId="grids_demo"
                />
```

I've succesfully display with openlayers.
how can i use wmts with flexviewer?

Comment: What does the getCapabilities for these two services look like?  Are the two WMTS services using the same spatial reference?  Are you using any other layers (that might have different spatial references than these two)?

Comment: it was a bug in flexviewer for parsing
  tileMatrixSetId field. fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the latest version of [Flex Viewer 3.7](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/index.cfm?fuseaction=download.main&downloadid=1338) and here is the config.xml snippet that successfully display the WMTS Layer as basemap:

```
    <basemaps>
    <layer label="Sample WMTS layer" type="wmts" visible="true" useproxy="true" 
   imageformat="png" url="http://v2.suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts"
   servicemode="KVP" layerid="opengeo:countries" 
   tilematrixsetid="EPSG:4326"/>
    </basemaps>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Yes. at the time I was asking the question, there were bugs in the flexviewer and the arcgis lib api.